# How to separate console input and output while multithreading in Rust?

Tags: rust, console

I tried to create a console for server where user can insert commands while output is active.

I have server loop and input loop in different threads and everything works, but print and input text clashes.
How I can fix that?

Simple code demonstrating my case:

```
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

fn main() {

    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            let mut input = String::new();
            std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
            // Deal with inserted command
            println!("Command: {}", input);
        }
    });
    // Game loop
    loop {
        println!("Game/server message");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500));
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

But I want the entered text to always stay at the bottom, how I can achieve that?

I tried to find solution with crossterm and termion, but I didn't find a solution.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: rustyline has an [example](https://github.com/kkawakam/rustyline/blob/6e717816025f6a6258e64da82b36894826124005/examples/external_print.rs#L10) on how to do that. Your input will need to be a tty.